# Browse Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, theme, admin-panel, 404, admin-login

I installed quickstart package of a Magento 2 Theme. Now I can't browse the Admin Panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the **.htaccess** file in the root. Create the .htaccess file from the **sample htaccess** given by magento. Or you can also download this file from : [github magento2 repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2)

if this doesn't work please comment. There could be ssl / file permission issue.